# HQL Join Path Expected for Join

Tags: java, hibernate, left-join, hql

I have a Java class **Application.java**

```
public class Application implements Serializable {
    private Long key;
    private String appName;
    private Long locationKey;
    private Long ownerKey;
    private Long unitKey;
    private Boolean active;

    //getters and setters
}
```

The locationKey corresponds to location table, ownerKey represents Person table and unitKey represents Unit Table. I have not mentioned any relationship between tables.

I want to retrieve a list of applications, with the corresponding location, owner and unit names.

I created a new Java class. **AplicationDetail.java**

```
public class ApplicationDetails implements Serializable {
    private Long key;
    private String appName;
    private String location;
    private String ownerName;
    private String unitName;

    public ApplicationDetails(){
    }

    public ApplicationDetails(Long key, String appName, String location, String ownerName, String unitName){
        super();
        this.key=key;
        this.appName=appName;
        this.location=location;
        this.ownerName=ownerName;
        this.unitName=unitName;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

In dao, I wrote the following query.

```
"select new com.myapp.domain.ApplicationDetail(application.key, application.appName, location.name as location, person.firstName || person.lastName as ownerName, unit.name as unitName)
from Application application, Location location, Person person, Unit unit 
where application.isCurrent = ? and application.locationKey = location.locationKey
and application.ownerKey = person.personKey and application.unitKey = unit.unitKey";
```

By the above query, I am getting list of aplication with proper values. But the problem is it is not returning all application rows.

Sometimes the locationKey or ownerKey or unitKey can be null in table. Or the key containing row may not be present in the respective associating table.

In any case I want all the applications to return satisfying the condition active to true;

So I wrote a **LEFT OUTER JOIN** QUERY.

```
"select new com.myapp.domain.ApplicationDetail(application.key, application.appName, location.name as location, person.firstName || person.lastName as ownerName, unit.name as unitName)
from Application application
LEFT OUTER JOIN Location location WITH application.locationKey = location.locationKey
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person person WITH application.ownerKey = person.personKey
LEFT OUTER JOIN Unit unit WITH application.unitKey = unit.unitKey
where application.isCurrent = ?";
```

But when I running, I am getting Exception

```
03 Sep 2014 17:05:02 ERROR [tomcat-http--32] ErrorCounter.reportError(54) |  Path expected for join!
03 Sep 2014 17:05:02 ERROR [tomcat-http--32] ErrorCounter.reportError(50) |  Path expected for join!
 Path expected for join!
```

.
.
.
.
.

```
03 Sep 2014 17:05:02 ERROR [tomcat-http--32] ErrorCounter.reportError(54) |  Invalid path: 'dimLocation.locationName'
03 Sep 2014 17:05:02 ERROR [tomcat-http--32] ErrorCounter.reportError(50) |  Invalid path: 'dimLocation.locationName'
 Invalid path: 'location.name
```

Similarly for other fields also.  Also it is showing there is no constructor.

```
03 Sep 2014 17:05:02 ERROR [tomcat-http--32] ErrorCounter.reportError(54) |  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.myapp.domain.ApplicationDetail]
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.myapp.domain.ApplicationDetail]
03 Sep 2014 17:05:02 ERROR [tomcat-http--32] ErrorCounter.reportError(50) |  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.myapp.domain.ApplicationDetail]
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.myapp.domain.ApplicationDetail]
 Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.myapp.domain.ApplicationDetail]
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.myapp.domain.ApplicationDetail]
```

But I have constructor in my **ApplicationDetails.java** with parameters.

'

Comment: Do you have default constructor as well for `ApplicationDetails`?

Comment: Yes I have default constructor also. I have to create object in some classes

Comment: please add all the constructors that you have in your `ApplicationDetails` class to your question.

Comment: @Chaitanya Please check

Comment: Are you saying that you have not mapped any of the associations between your domain objects? Or have you merely omitted them from your question?

Comment: @carbontax I have not mapped any associations.

Comment: @iProgrammer This makes it very difficult for you to use JPA or Hibernate in your project. You should either map your domain objects or just use straight SQL